# DirectoryNotFoundException when trying to save image to wwwroot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322085/how-to-save-iformfile-to-disk) I came up with this code to save a file

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(string office, IFormFile file)
{
    if (file.Length > 0) {
        var filePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, 
            _configuration["SydneyFloorplanPath"]));

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)) {
            file.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new{office = office});
}
```

But I get a super annoying issue when instantiating `FileStream`:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\images\Floorplan\sydney.pdf'.'

But That's not the path that I need. The `Images` folder sits in my project under `wwwroot\images`...

what is the point of `WebRootPath` if it doesn't actually give me a usable, relative path?

Note that `_environment` is an injected `IHostingEnvironment`

I also noticed that if I call

```
var two = _environment.WebRootPath;
```

the varaible contains the full path... `"C:\\Users\\bassie\\source\\repos\\TFS\\DSSTools\\wwwroot"`

But after calling `Path.Combine`, I suddenly have `"C:\\images\\Floorplan\\sydney.pdf"` ... why?

**Edit:**

_environment is a `IHostingEnvironment`, eg:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AspNetCorePathMapping
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

            return Content(webRootPath + "\n" + contentRootPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats `_environment`? Are you using [HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.internal.hostingenvironment.webrootpath?view=aspnetcore-2.0)? Are you using Kestral or IIS?

Comment: @JeremyThompson apologies - yes its a `IHostingEnvironment`

Comment: Looks like there was a change from RC1 and there is a GitHub bug about it being null. Can you confirm your code looks like this: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/22/getting-the-web-root-path-and-the-content-root-path-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @JeremyThompson I updated my question. `WebrootPath` itself contains the path that I need, but after calling `Path.Combine` it just doesn't work any more... This makes no sense

Comment: Oh `Path.Combine` often does stuff like that to me. Its tends to be that a one of the parts ends with a double slash or a single slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working with

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(string office, IFormFile file)
{
    var webRootPath  = _environment.WebRootPath;
    var floorPlanPath =  _configuration["SydneyFloorplanPath"];

    if (file.Length > 0) {
        var filePath1 = Path.Combine(floorPlanPath,webRootPath.ReplaceFirst("/", ""));

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath1, FileMode.Create)) {
            file.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new{office = office});
}
```

Where `ReplaceFirst` is a simple `StringExtension`

```
public static string ReplaceFirst(this string text, string search, string replace)
{
    int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
    if (pos < 0)
    {
        return text;
    }
    return $"{text.Substring(0, pos)}{replace}{text.Substring(pos + search.Length)}";
}
```

So it seems the leading `/` in `webRootPath` was breaking my `Path.Combine` call