# Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC How to upload photos in the project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

**Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC In my project**, the user needs to upload a photo and I want to keep the photo under wwwroot / database. In the database, only the path to the photo is required, but every time my IFromfile object comes as null. Thank you from now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the following steps.

1. Create a model `Image`:

   ```
   public class Image
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Path { get; set; } 
   }
   ```
2. Create a folder `Images` under your `wwwroot`
3. The index view code:

   ```
   @model Image

   <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="uploadFile" class="form-control" />
       <input type="submit" value="submit" id="sub" />
   </form>
   ```
4. Controller:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
       private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

       public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
       {
           _context = context;
           _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
       }

       public IActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync(Image image,IFormFile uploadFile)
       {
           if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.Length > 0)
           {
               var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName);
               var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images", fileName);
               image.Path = filePath;

               _context.Images.Add(image);
               _context.SaveChanges();

               using (var fileSrteam = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
               {
                    await uploadFile.CopyToAsync(fileSrteam);
               }
           }

           return View();
       }
   ```

Results:

[image]

Comment: You don't await `CopToAsync()`, and you let users overwrite each other's files by using the provided filename from the upload, instead of generating one serverside. Also, the OP's problem is _"IFromfile object comes as null"_, so the problem is with their client code, which isn't show.

Comment: I don't know who pity-upvoted this answer, but it is copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63822872/, including `fileSrteam` typo and non-unique filename issue, and made worse by removing `await`.